# Flask simple routing going wrong

Tags: flask, routes

I am having an issue with simple routing in Flask that I can't get my head around.

Here is the problematic function and decorator:

```
@app.route('/download/<filepath>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filepath):
    return(send_file(filepath, as_attachment=True))
```

Being triggered by the following javascript :

```
var route='/download/'+filepath
$('#main').append('<div id="download"><div>Your report has been created</div><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="'+route+'">Download report</a></div>');
```

The 'Not Found' error implies a problem with routing, not a simple IOerror to do with the filepath.

But the routing seems OK to me, is there some obvious mistake I am making?
Thanks v much!

Edit: in Windows if that is relevant

Comment: It's hard to see with just these snippets. Are you sure the route is being registered? If so, try returning a string response to make sure it's not an issue with `send_file`. Also, without validation on the filepath, this is a potential security flaw.

Comment: 'try returning a string response to make sure it's not an issue with send_file'
Could you clarify what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Also I am not sure what you mean by validation on the filepath

Comment: You're basically opening access to download any file on your server. Try putting a python file and see if it downloads your source code. The point is, you should explicitly check the `filepath` value to ensure only what you want exposed is exposed (maybe put them all in the same subdirectory like "public")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the converter types in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules) that specify the type of argument:

```
string  (default) accepts any text without a slash
path    like string but also accepts slashes
```

I suspect that your variable needs to be of type `path`, rather than the default `string`:

```
@app.route('/download/<path:filepath>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: This was the cause of the problem, thanks for the concise and prompt response